# IT Team Management and Monitoring

Tags: project-management, monitoring, hosted

I'm looking for a hosted PM system for what I assume is a fairly typical project-management/ticketing role.  Essentially, at any moment we want to be able to see:

1. Tasks by priority and due date, (including sequencing by dependencies)
2. Who is doing what.  But not just who has been *assigned* what, but more particularly: *of the tasks, assigned or not, **what people are presently working on?***  Sort of like a source-control for tasks: You check out a task when you're actually working it, and check it back in when you've moved on to something else.
3. Who has done what over some recent period.  E.g., *DevA checked out Task 1, but turned it back in marked incomplete later that day*.

On the task side it's the usual: We want to create projects consisting of hierarchical, prioritized tasks, potentially with dependencies.  E.g., Project A has task t, due in a week, consisting of subtasks x, y, and z.  Z can't be done until x and y are done.  Y has priority 1, X has priority 2.

We want users to be able to:

- Create and organize projects and tasks
- Triage tasks (i.e., change priority)
- Assign tasks
- **Pick up tasks (a.k.a., "check out" to work on)**
- Annotate tasks
- Mark tasks complete

Comment: Sounds like the standard project management tool. Have you checked existing answers (just click the [project-management tag](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management)? See e.g. my answers [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/23192/185), [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/21524/185) and [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/7501/185) for a good candidate matching your requirements.

Comment: @Izzy - Yes, I've looked at trac.  Biggest problem is there's no hosted offering.  I'll clarify my question to emphasize a feature I think it lacks.

Comment: Hosting is a different thing we don't deal with here (consider self-hosting). As for "that feature": I wouldn't wonder if there's a specific Plugin to Trac for that. But even if not, you could realize that using the "Assigned-To" field: The dev self-assigns and later resets (unless solved). Subtasks have a plugin (MasterTicket). Priorities are supported "natively". Annotation is done via comments. Status is available "natively", incl. "complete" (aka "Fixed" by default, you can change that).

Comment: I wonder if you'd consider to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) instead of just leaving a little comment? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was migrating out of Podio, because that is prone to scatter things across "apps," preventing a convenient view of "everything," and also because its customization potential is relatively limited and immature.  It just feels bulky.

I began migrating to Jira, which I've used before.  That's OK, but then another developer suggested YouTrack by JetBrains.

I've settled on YouTrack because it was pretty good "out-of-the-box," and I was able to customize it to be "just right" for my purposes without much trouble.

One thing I will note is that dependency mappings are deficient in everything I've looked at.

The other thing I'll note is that my concept of "checking-out" tasks isn't clearly implemented anywhere I've seen.  I.e., one has to kludge to designate a group of people for a task and then allow individuals to mark it as "I'm working on this right now, nobody touch without me releasing it."