# With which tool I can draw version control(git) graphs?

Tags: version-control, graphic-design

I want to draw Directed Acyclic Graphs(DAG) as below. I have tried Visio, only to find it's very unhandy to do this. I need to draw the graph manually rather than produce one according to the logs in the .git directory.

[image: example graph]
<sup>Example graph (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Do you have any recommendations? Since I may only use it once in a blue moon a free-of-charge one is the best.

My OS is Ubuntu. Since I'm a student I expect that it would provide a free plan for us. I don't like drawing graphs in a clike-and-drag way, so a friendly text language is highly appreciated. It doesn't matter too much when it comes to vestor formats or bitmap formats. I will only take a screenshot of the graph to put in MS Word. Sorry. I was kind of forced to write my thesis using Word. If there is no free one available I'll give graphviz a try.

Comment: It's duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977859/timeline-graph-for-version-control-systems

Comment: PS: Take a look at *Trac* (see [my answer here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/23192/185)). It's certainly much more than you've asked for, but it includes drawing those graphs automatically (with the proper plugin, available for free) based on your repository. Btw: what version control system are you trying to visualize? There might be other tools which can provide this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a friendly text language is highly appreciated

That reminds me of **[Graphviz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz)**, though the output would look a bit different from normal directed acyclic graph (please check the linked Wikipedia page for other examples). You simply define the dependencies/links one per line (like `A -> B`), define formatting in a similar way (`A [color=blue]`, `B [shape=box]`), and then have it create the graph. That "text language" is called **[Dot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language)**.

That's basically what's used by *Trac* (which I already mentioned and recommended in [my answer here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/23192/185)). Some simple example to visualize what it is about, taken from [this tutorial](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf):

[image]
<sup>Graphviz example: "Directed Acyclic Graph" (source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph); click graphic for larger variant)</sup>

```
// Directed Acyclic Graph

digraph G {
size ="4,4";
main [shape=box]; /* this is a comment */
main -> parse [weight=8];
parse -> execute;
main -> init [style=dotted];
main -> cleanup;
execute -> { make_string; printf}
init -> make_string;
edge [color=red]; // so is this
main -> printf [style=bold,label="100 times"];
make_string [label="make a\nstring"];
node [shape=box,style=filled,color=".7 .3 1.0"];
execute -> compare;
}
```

Graphviz is available cross-platform for free (just run a `apt-cache search graphviz` to find all related packages, or search for the term "graphviz" with Aptitude/Synaptics (or "Software Center", or whatever you use as frontend ;) No need to take screenshots; plenty of ways to have Graphviz export to a number of formats from bitmaps to vector graphics. I'm using Graphviz myself for visualization (e.g. the graph on [this page](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) is made using it, and my [HyperSQL](https://github.com/IzzySoft/HyperSQL) uses it to generate its dependency graphs), so – for these specific topics – I can really recommend it. Might need a little "playing around" though to get the wanted results.

Comment: And I find this: http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf